# Import symbols with wildcard, but rename or ignore some of them

Tags: scala, import, wildcard

I want to import most Scala Swing symbols with a few exceptions. The exceptions are classes for which I have provided my own implementation, like `ToggleButton`, which has only a rudimentary implementation in the `scala.swing` (no constructor taking `Action`).

I can use different names for my classes (like `ToggleButtonEx`), but this makes using them less natural.

I am looking for something like:

```
import scala.swing.{ToggleButton => SToggleButton, _} // import all but ToggleButton
import mydomain.swing._ // contains ToggleButton as well
```

Is there some pattern matching syntax for import, or some other way to achieve this?

Comment: To my surprise, the rename in wildcard import as written in the question seems to work. I am not sure what I did wrong when trying it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an underscore to exclude certain names.

```
import scala.swing.{ToggleButton => _, _}
import mydomain.swing._
```

An alternative solution is to import `ToggleButton` individually. Since individual imports take precedence over wildcard ones, the reference to `ToggleButton` will no longer be ambiguous.

```
import scala.swing._
import mydomain.swing.{ToggleButton, _}
```