# Mocking a dynamic class method argument using scalatest/mockiton

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, scalatest

this is how im mocking my service call and returning a fake result:

```
when(myService.doSomething("",fakeRequestAsModel)) thenReturn fakeResult

val result = call(controller.myActionMethod(), request)
```

the problem is in the controller method `myActionMethod` when I call `doSomething` and passing the arguments im calling some property that that will only return something in production...

```
def myActionMethod() ... = {

   myService.doSomething(request.getSomeValue,requestAsModel)
   ...
}
```

so, `getSomeValue` is a method i can call only in production, it comes with a 3rd party library and I cant override it.

How can I still mock this call so `request.getSomeValue` wont throw me an exception?

and `request.getSomeValue` is dynamic, I cant unfortunately put it in configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// we rename this because Scala defines `eq` on `AnyRef`
import org.mockito.Matchers.{eq => eqMockito, _} 
...
when(myService.doSomething(anyString(), eqMockito(fakeRequestAsModel))) 
  thenReturn fakeResult
```

Here we want Mockito to return this answer when *any string* is sent and exact `fakeRequestAsModel`, which is what you want.

---

Notes:

1. Be careful not to mix `any` matchers with normal values, you cant say:
   `when(myService.doSomething(anyString(), fakeRequestAsModel))`.
   You need to wrap normal value with `eqMockito()` method.
2. You can use `any[classOf[T]]` for type-parametrized arguments.
3. Be extra careful with [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36971704/scala-playframework-mockito-executioncontext-null).

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks man! that helped. can you explain `import org.mockito.Matchers.{eq => eqMockito, _}` this import please? mainly `eq => eqMockito`

Comment: @JohnBigs you're welcome! In Scala you can **rename** imported stuff, to avoid name conflicts. For example you want to refer to `java.util.List` as `JList` or something like that. Here we rename a method called `eq` to `eqMockito` (or whatever you want to call it). You can also exclude some stuff from importing, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945005/import-symbols-with-wildcard-but-rename-or-ignore-some-of-them

Comment: so we only changed the name so it wont clash with scala eq?

Comment: Yes, that's the only reason. Feel free to experiment without it.